# How to add a select all option to a jquery filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I have managed to start working with this filter and the only thing left to do is understand how to allow the 'Select All' function to work properly. It keeps breaking on me.

```js
// Javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        $("." + inputValue).toggle();
    }); 
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visible: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.box {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.red{ background: #ff0000; }
.green{ background: #228B22; }
.blue{ background: #0000ff; }
label{ margin-right: 15px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden" value="all">Select All
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden" value="red">Red
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden" value="green">Green
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden" value="blue">Blue
      </label>

      <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
      <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
      <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using .attr("value"), you could use just .val(), as you are using the this ojbect binding to the element. Give that a try

Comment: It completely depends on how you want it to work. If you only want it to show or hide the divs, all you have to do is add the class `all` to those elements and make sure the css class makes them visible. You could add `!important` there to make sure it overrides the other classes. If however you want the other checkboxes to become selected, this will become a whole lot more complicated. As you would need to automaticly select all if the other 3 are selected and remove all if one of them is deselected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `addClass()` , `removeClass()` and `toggleClass()` it will be much easier to achieve this

- You can use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`
- Use `if` statement to check the selectAll checkbox value
- Add `.box.show` class to your css style sheet
- With `checkbox` use `.change` instead of `.click`

```js
// Javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).val();  // input value
        if(inputValue == 'all' && $(this).is(":checked")){   // check the selectAll value and this is checked
          $(".box").addClass('show'); // Add class show to all the box
        }else if(inputValue == 'all' && !$(this).is(":checked")){
          $(".box").removeClass('show');
        }else{
          $("." + inputValue).toggleClass('show'); // toggle class show
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.box {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.box.show{
  display : block;
}
.red{ background: #ff0000; }
.green{ background: #228B22; }
.blue{ background: #0000ff; }
label{ margin-right: 15px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden" value="all">Select All
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden" value="red">Red
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden" value="green">Green
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden" value="blue">Blue
      </label>

      <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
      <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
      <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>**This code is just for start** .. Still a lot of work needed depending on what you're trying to do</sup>

Additional:

- Nothing called `visible:` in css it should be `visibility:`
- To get the count of checked checkbox `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length`

**Let's go farther away and make it more complicated**

Let's say you want to add some action to the filter checkboxes also the selectAll checkbox to change classes or change the selectAll button style or check if all buttons checked or not if its checked then change selectAll button class and so on

**The main idea in the next code is :** The selectAll button will change the checkboxes to checked or unchecked and this change will effect the show/hide boxes by itself so no need here to make the selectAll button to control show/hide boxes . **It will control the checkboxes not the boxes**

```js
// Javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.filter input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        var input = $(this);  // this input
        var inputValue = input.val();  // this input value
        var inputLabel = input.closest('label'); // get the closest label
        
        if(input.hasClass('all-boxes')){ // if its selectAll button
          ToggleCheckboxes(input);
        }else{
          input.toggleClass('Checked notChecked');
          inputLabel.toggleClass('btn-success');
          ToggleBoxes(inputValue);
          // get checked checkboxes
          var countAllCheckboxes = $('.filter-boxes').length;
          var countChecked = $('.filter-boxes.Checked').length;
          if(countAllCheckboxes == countChecked){
            $(".all-boxes").prop('checked' , true).closest('label').addClass('btn-success');
          }else{
            $(".all-boxes").prop('checked' , false).closest('label').removeClass('btn-success');
          }
        }
    });
});

// show/hide boxes
function ToggleBoxes(Selector){
  $("." + Selector).toggleClass('show');
}

// toggle the checkboxes to checked/unchecked
function ToggleCheckboxes(Selector){
  var GetChecked = Selector.is(':checked')? 'notChecked':'Checked';
  console.log(GetChecked);
  $('.filter-boxes.'+ GetChecked).change();
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.box {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.box.show{
  display : block;
}
.red{ background: #ff0000; }
.green{ background: #228B22; }
.blue{ background: #0000ff; }
label{ margin-right: 15px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 filter">
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden all-boxes" value="all">Select All
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden filter-boxes notChecked" value="red">Red
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden filter-boxes notChecked" value="green">Green
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" class="hidden filter-boxes notChecked" value="blue">Blue
      </label>

      <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
      <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
      <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To change white spaces heights between items .. in css style

```
.item-selected {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 5px;  /* <<<<<< here */
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

And the reason of different height of white spaces between items this is because all `.col-` classes has a `min-height : 1px;` .. To avoid this copy/paste the next code to your css stylesheet

```
#selfPacedList .col-sm-12{
  min-height : 0px;
}
```

Comment: Well done, sir. I was just working on this, but your solution is much more elegant than what I had come up with. Very nice!

Comment: Wow, @Mohamed-Yousef! Thank you very much. I'm just not that great with jQuery.

Comment: You're totally welcome @webfrogs .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: @webfrogs I updated my answer with a more complicated code you may need .. Have a nice day :-)

Comment: I had done something similar on my end already. But I like you'rs better. Thanks @Mohamed-Yousef.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef - I'm seeing a lot of extra white space after I start filtering the items. I assume there's a way to apply the `$trim()` function, but not sure how to implement. Here's a **[pen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/bGbaELy)** to look at.

Comment: which white space?? @webfrogs

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Here's an example, where I've selected **Negotiation** - **[Codepen](http://prntscr.com/p2by2z)**

As you can see there is a lot of difference in the spacing between items. Is there a way to tighten that up?

Comment: I see it now. Thanks.